# Checking if array element is empty with for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, scripting

Can you please provide a sample code for checking if array element is empty using for loop?

None of this worked for me:

```
declare -a f=( 'file' )
for ((i=0; ${f[$i]}; i++); do echo "i: $i"; done
for ((i=0; `test -n "${f[$i]}"`; i++); do echo "i: $i"; done
```

What I wanted is to keep this braces-like for style and iterate over array, following solution worked for me:

```
for((i=0; i < ${#f[@]}; i++))
```

Does any other syntax available?

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
for i in ${f[@]}
do
   if [ -z "$f[$i]" ]
   then
       #do whatever you want
   fi  
done
```